# CPU with Efficent and Performance cores: Only Efficient-cores are used

Tags: c++, performance, winapi, cpu-usage

I develop a Windows C++ console Application that utilizes many cores (configurable). A couple of years ago i added processorGroups in order to utilize more than 64 CPUs etc. which all works fine.

Since a while we use i.e the [i7-12700K](https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/products/sku/134594/intel-core-i712700k-processor-25m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz/specifications.html) which has some Performance and some Efficient-cores. Now after a Update from Windows 10 to Windows 11 we find that our application uses only the 4 Efficient-cores while the Performance-cores just idle around.

How can that be fixed?
Is there a API for this or is it a Administrators setting?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you cannot force the use of P-cores since Windows is managing these cores.
Windows will use P-cores only if the task is intensive, if E-cores are enough they will be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

We found out about this topic the following:

Or Software is started via a Windows service. The service is a little helper program written in Visual Basic (VB). This utility starts the work horse application (C++).

The performance Cores WILL be used in the following cases:

- Start the C++ Application "as Administrator" (or from a command line window that runs "as Administrator").
- Set the process Affinity in the Windows UI to the last 4 Cores only (which are the performance cores)
- Set the Priority of the Application to "High"

A Post that helped quite a bit:
https://www.xmg.gg/en/news-tips-and-tricks-rendering-e-cores/

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups)

> Starting with Windows 11 and Windows Server 2022, it is no longer the
> case that applications are constrained by default to a single
> processor group. Instead, processes and their threads have processor
> affinities that by default span all processors in the system, across
> multiple groups on machines with more than 64 processors.

So its likely that you are effectively no longer eliminating the E cores from your group the app has access to all the CPUs, and the scheduler is prioritising the power-efficient E cores because it doesn't think you need the P core power. That, howveer, is an assumption of mine given the details in your question.

Comment: We dont use Processor groups on this machine as only 1 Group is reported. Is that as expected?

Comment: you tell me in your question you use processor groups, and now you say you don't use processor groups?!

Comment: If the OS reports only one group (as in this case) there is no use in setting them.